# nested json to csv using pandas normalize

Tags: python, pandas, csv

With given script I am able to get output as I showed in a screenshot,
but there is a column named as *cve.description.description_data* which is again in json format. I want to extract that data as well.

```
import json 
import pandas as pd 
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize 
#load json object
with open('nvdcve-1.0-modified.json') as f:
   d = json.load(f)
#tells us parent node is 'programs'
nycphil = json_normalize(d['CVE_Items'])
nycphil.head(3)
works_data = json_normalize(data=d['CVE_Items'], record_path='cve')
works_data.head(3)
nycphil.to_csv("test4.csv")
```

If I change `works_data = json_normalize(data=d['CVE_Items'], record_path='cve.descr')` it gives this error:

> "result = result[spec] KeyError: 'cve.description'"

JSON format as follows:

```
{
   "CVE_data_type":"CVE",
   "CVE_data_format":"MITRE",
   "CVE_data_version":"4.0",
   "CVE_data_numberOfCVEs":"1000",
   "CVE_data_timestamp":"2018-04-04T00:00Z",
   "CVE_Items":[
      {
         "cve":{
            "data_type":"CVE",
            "data_format":"MITRE",
            "data_version":"4.0",
            "CVE_data_meta":{
               "ID":"CVE-2001-1594",
               "ASSIGNER":"cve@mitre.org"
            },
            "affects":{
               "vendor":{
                  "vendor_data":[
                     {
                        "vendor_name":"gehealthcare",
                        "product":{
                           "product_data":[
                              {
                                 "product_name":"entegra_p&r",
                                 "version":{
                                    "version_data":[
                                       {
                                          "version_value":"*"
                                       }
                                    ]
                                 }
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            "problemtype":{
               "problemtype_data":[
                  {
                     "description":[
                        {
                           "lang":"en",
                           "value":"CWE-255"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            },
            "references":{
               "reference_data":[
                  {
                     "url":"http://apps.gehealthcare.com/servlet/ClientServlet/2263784.pdf?DOCCLASS=A&REQ=RAC&DIRECTION=2263784-100&FILENAME=2263784.pdf&FILEREV=5&DOCREV_ORG=5&SUBMIT=+  ACCEPT+"
                  },
                  {
                     "url":"http://www.forbes.com/sites/thomasbrewster/2015/07/10/vulnerable- "
                  },
                  {
                     "url":"https://ics-cert.us-cert.gov/advisories/ICSMA-18-037-02"
                  },
                  {
                     "url":"https://twitter.com/digitalbond/status/619250429751222277"
                  }
               ]
            },
            "description":{
               "description_data":[
                  {
                     "lang":"en",
                     "value":"GE Healthcare eNTEGRA P&R has a password of (1) value."
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         "configurations":{
            "CVE_data_version":"4.0",
            "nodes":[
               {
                  "operator":"OR",
                  "cpe":[
                     {
                        "vulnerable":true,
                        "cpe22Uri":"cpe:/a:gehealthcare:entegra_p%26r",
                        "cpe23Uri":"cpe:2.3:a:gehealthcare:entegra_p\\&r:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         "impact":{
            "baseMetricV2":{
               "cvssV2":{
                  "version":"2.0",
                  "vectorString":"(AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:C/I:C/A:C)",
                  "accessVector":"NETWORK",
                  "accessComplexity":"LOW",
                  "authentication":"NONE",
                  "confidentialityImpact":"COMPLETE",
                  "integrityImpact":"COMPLETE",
                  "availabilityImpact":"COMPLETE",
                  "baseScore":10.0
               },
               "severity":"HIGH",
               "exploitabilityScore":10.0,
               "impactScore":10.0,
               "obtainAllPrivilege":false,
               "obtainUserPrivilege":false,
               "obtainOtherPrivilege":false,
               "userInteractionRequired":false
            }
         },
         "publishedDate":"2015-08-04T14:59Z",
         "lastModifiedDate":"2018-03-28T01:29Z"
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to flatten all data.

[image: Output csv]

Comment: Except for URLs, where is the repetition in this JSON? This looks to be one row output.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the multiple URLs delineate between rows and all else meta data repeats, consider a recursive function call to extract every key-value pair in nested json object, *d*.

The recursive function will call `global` to update the needed global objects to be binded into a list of dictionaries for `pd.DataFrame()` call. Last loop at end updates the recursive function's dictionary, *inner*, to integrate the different urls (stored in *multi*)

```
import json 
import pandas as pd 

# load json object
with open('nvdcve-1.0-modified.json') as f:
   d = json.load(f)

multi = []; inner = {}

def recursive_extract(i):
    global multi, inner

    if type(i) is list:
        if len(i) == 1:
            for k,v in i[0].items():
                if type(v) in [list, dict]:
                    recursive_extract(v)
                else:                
                    inner[k] = v
        else:
            multi = i

    if type(i) is dict:
        for k,v in i.items():
            if type(v) in [list, dict]:
                recursive_extract(v)
            else:                
                inner[k] = v

recursive_extract(d['CVE_Items'])

data_dict = []
for i in multi:    
    tmp = inner.copy()
    tmp.update(i)
    data_dict.append(tmp)

df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
df.to_csv('Output.csv')
```

**Output** *(all columns the same except for URL, widened for emphasis)*

[image: Excel DF Output]

Comment: Still same output? Can you please provide entire python code. I am quite new to python so didnt really get it

Comment: I have copied over your `import` lines and json load, the only items needed for this solution. Please run this in an entirely separate script to yield output.